# Can and should you observe changes to an ObservedObject from regular Swift code

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am a bit lost in Combine at the moment. I have an ObservableObject. This is mostly because this model is used in SwiftUI and having properties @Published means swiftUI can update with them. However now I also have swift code that would like to listen to changes.

```
class TheModelClass: ObservableObject {
```

However this code does not compile... And I am a bit surprised?

```
modelChangeSink = self.model.objectWillChange.sink {
   let newValue: PageManagerObservableModel = $0 // This line does not compile
}
```

With the compile time error being `Cannot convert value of type 'ObservableObjectPublisher.Output' to specified type 'PageManagerObservableModel'` which I cant 100% interpret. I am ideally hoping to do things like

```
if (self.model.property != newValue.property) {
  // On property change
}
```

Should I be using something other than ObservableObject to do this? I cant find a lot of examples of people using ObservableObject outside of SwiftUI so perhaps I should be using something different?

Comment: If you want to do something on property change, why not use a `sink` on the property? So `model.$property.sink { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObservableObjectPublisher` has an associated type called `Output` and that is the type of the values that it publishes.  Inside of your model change `sink`, that is all the information that the compiler has.  That type must trace back to a concrete type, but the compiler doesn't know what that concrete type is.  You're telling it to put whatever value that may be into a variable of type `PageManagerObservableModel`, but the compiler doesn't have enough information to say that `ObservableObjectPublisher.Output` and `PageManagerObservableModel` are the same type, so it gives an error.

In all liklihood, `TheModelClass.objectWillChange` has an `Output` type of `Void` (it was in the small sample I tried). This basically means it will invoke subscribers, but not pass them a value.

In normal usage when you want to use ObservableObject you are interested in specific properties of the object so you'd do something like:

```
import UIKit

class WatchMe: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myValue: Int;
    init() {
        myValue = 10
    }
}

let watchable = WatchMe()
let subscription = watchable.$myValue.sink { newValue in
    print(newValue)
}

watchable.myValue = 20
watchable.myValue = 30
```

The value I'm *actually* interested in knowing about is `myValue`. Certainly you could use code like this to communicate between models.  You should be aware that the observer is invoked during the `willSet` portion of the property being changed.  So at the time your subscription is invoked, you get the new value, before it's actually assigned to the `ObservedObject`.

Having said that, in *my opinion*, and as you seem to have noticed, `ObservableObject` and the newer variant `@Observable` are a publish/subscribe that shines in the context of SwiftUI. But I've had limited success using them outside of that context.

I usually find that one of the other Observer Pattern implementations in the system seem to fit the models I create better. iOS has lots of implementations of the Observer Pattern to choose from. Off the top of my head:

- Create your own Combine Subject (`CurrentValueSubject` or `PassthroughSubject`) and create your sink on those.
- Use the [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-delegates-to-customize-object-behavior) to create a dedicated interface for sending change messages.
- A variation on the delegate pattern would be to register a function with the model that is invoked each time an interesting value changes.
- Use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) to broadcast a far reaching notification.

You could also go with Swift Concurrency and use an `AsyncSequence` to create a stream of changed values over time.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableObject` (and its `@Published` properties) is designed to invalidate a SwiftUI `View` so `body` is called, you wouldn't use it in regular swift code. Firstly it's inefficient (the whole object sends a change rather than each property); it also notifies at the wrong time, i.e. will-change instead of did-change, so properties don't have the new values yet making it rather complicated to get them. The reason its designed this way is so SwiftUI can coalesce all the changes to properties and only call `body` once (in the next event loop). So great for SwiftUI, terrible for anything else.

So instead, make your Swift code use one of the other patterns, `NSObject` is a good one, then you can make an `ObservableObject` with a custom `objectWillChange` publisher to watch for changes in the `NSObject` e.g. using a KVO publisher to connect it up to SwiftUI. This is mentioned in [Data Flow Through SwiftUI (WWDC 2019)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/).